# What does "@" mean in Windows batch scripts

Tags: windows, batch-file

I saw `@` is used in such contexts:

```
@echo off

@echo start eclipse.exe
```

What does `@` mean here?

Comment: Quick note: @ sign in a script suppresses the output of the corresponding command.

Answer (score 260, accepted):

It means not to output the respective command. Compare the following two batch files:

```
@echo foo
```

and

```
echo foo
```

The former has only `foo` as output while the latter prints

```
H:\Stuff>echo foo 
foo
```

(here, at least). As can be seen the command that is run is visible, too.

`echo off` will turn this off for the complete batch file. However, the `echo off` call itself would still be visible. Which is why you see `@echo off` in the beginning of batch files. Turn off command echoing *and* don't echo the command turning it off.

Removing that line (or commenting it out) is often a helpful debugging tool in more complex batch files as you can see what is run prior to an error message.

Answer (score 47):

It means "don't echo the command to standard output".

Rather strangely,

```
echo off
```

will send `echo off` to the output! So,

```
@echo off
```

sets this automatic echo behaviour off - and stops it for all future commands, too.

Source: http://www.microsoft.com/resources/documentation/windows/xp/all/proddocs/en-us/batch.mspx?mfr=true

Answer (score 35):

By default, a batch file will display its command as it runs. The purpose of this first command which **@echo off** is to turn off this display. The command "echo off" turns off the display for the whole script, except for the "echo off" command itself. **The "at" sign "@" in front makes the command apply to itself as well.**

Comment: I can't see any more or better information in your post, like in the other 5 year old posts.

Comment: For me, this was more understandable.

Comment: @Arash, same for me.  The other answers fail to mention that the [execution of] the batch file will show the commands as it runs and that `echo off` will turn off this feature, which is essential to understanding the use of the additional **@**.

Answer (score 14):

The `@` disables echo for that one command. Without it, the `echo start eclipse.exe` line would print both the intended `start eclipse.exe` *and* the `echo start eclipse.exe` line.

The `echo off` turns off the by-default command echoing.

So `@echo off` silently turns off command echoing, and only output the batch author intended to be written is actually written.

Answer (score 13):

It inherits the meaning from DOS.

*From the '**@**' section of [Technical Notes > Programming > Batch File Commands (archived version)](http://web.archive.org/web/20161119150623/http://academic.evergreen.edu/projects/biophysics/technotes/program/batch.htm#@):*

> @: In DOS version 3.3 and later, hides the echo of a batch command. Any output generated by the command is echoed.
>
> The at-sign can be prefixed to any DOS command, program name, or batch file name within a batch file.

Without it, you could turn off command echoing using the `echo off` command, but that command would be echoed first.

Comment: Link is now broken

Comment: _(The edit queue is currently full, so I'm putting this here for now.)_ The most recent working 'archive.org' version of the above link _(the original page was last actually edited on 5 March 2006)_ is: [Technical Notes / Programming / Batch File Commands / @ _(archived from the original on 19 November 2016)_](http://web.archive.org/web/20161119150623/http://academic.evergreen.edu/projects/biophysics/technotes/program/batch.htm)

Answer (score 11):

In batch file:

1 @echo off(solo)=>output nothing
[image]

2 echo off(solo)=> the “echo off” shows in the command line

[image]

3 echo off(then echo something) =>
[image]

4 @echo off(then echo something)=>
[image]

See, echo off(solo), means no output in the command line, but itself shows;
@echo off(solo), means no output in the command line, neither itself;

Answer (score 7):

Another useful time to include @ is when you use `FOR` in the command line. For example:

```
FOR %F IN (*.*) DO ECHO %F
```

Previous line show *for every file*: the command prompt, the `ECHO` command, and the result of `ECHO` command. This way:

```
FOR %F IN (*.*) DO @ECHO %F
```

Just the result of `ECHO` command is shown.

Comment: @PsychoData: It is funny that you downvoted the only answer that provide an useful information additional to the other 4 answers that, by the while, already answered the question in the same way...

Comment: I downvoted because it wasn't an answer to his question. You don't even give an explanation of what the @ does. If you have cool examples of usage, great, but it still isn't an answer to his question. You might not also know that I also upvoted the answer with the bet explanation of what it does and where it comes from. I didn't just downvote for no reason. Your "answer" is not an answer. It is a somewhat related statement.

Answer (score 3):

you can include @ in a 'scriptBlock' like this:

```
@(
  echo don't echoed
  hostname
)
echo echoed
```

and especially do not do that :)

```
for %%a in ("@") do %%~aecho %%~a
```

Answer (score 0):

from [msdn](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/administration/windows-commands/echo):

> To prevent echoing a particular command in a batch file, insert an @ sign in front of the command. To prevent echoing all commands in a batch file, include the echo off command at the beginning of the file.