# What does @ mean in Windows Batch scripts?

Tags: batch-file

Let me take `bundle.bat` file from [RubyInstaller](http://rubyinstaller.org/) to represent an example.

```
@ECHO OFF
IF NOT "%~f0" == "~f0" GOTO :WinNT
@"ruby.exe" "C:/Ruby200/bin/bundle" %1 %2 %3 %4 %5 %6 %7 %8 %9
GOTO :EOF
:WinNT
@"ruby.exe" "%~dpn0" %*
```

I don't understand this:

1. What does `@` mean here `@"ruby.exe"` and what for double quotes?

Here [in the manual](http://www.infionline.net/~wtnewton/batch/batguide.html#1a) I found some explanation:

> Explanation - the first line prevents the commands from being
>   displayed, the @ in "@echo off" keeps *that*  line from displaying.

And here are my two test scripts.

**The first one:**

```
@ECHO OFF
@ECHO "123"
ECHO "123"
PAUSE
```

The output:

```
C:\win>batch.bat
"123"
"123"
```

`@` does't keep line from displaying.

**The second:**

I want to call `gem environment` command from batch file. And here I'm guided by the code from `bundle.bat` file. My code:

```
@ECHO OFF
@"gem environment"
PAUSE
```

The output is an error. Please notice two double quotes:

```
""gem environment"" is not a command or executable or package file.
```

But in `bundle.bat` the line `@"ruby.exe" "%~dpn0" %*` works.

Now I change my script:

```
@ECHO OFF
REM Call like this...
@gem environment
REM or call like this.
gem environment
PAUSE
```

Both work fine. The output:

```
RubyGems Environment:
  - RUBYGEMS VERSION: 2.0.3
  - RUBY VERSION: 2.0.0 (2013-02-24 patchlevel 0) [i386-mingw32]
  - INSTALLATION DIRECTORY: C:/Ruby200/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0
  - RUBY EXECUTABLE: C:/Ruby200/bin/ruby.exe
  - EXECUTABLE DIRECTORY: C:/Ruby200/bin
  ... and so on
```

So my questions are:

1. What is the meaning of `@` character in Batch script?
2. When do I have to double-quote the value after `@`?

Comment: You should ask those as three separate questions, since they require three separate answers.

Comment: Agree, I better delete the third one.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What does "@" mean in Windows batch scripts](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8486042/what-does-mean-in-windows-batch-scripts)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

### Question 1

Q1. What is the meaning of @ character in Batch script?

The `@` character does indeed prevent the line from being displayed.  It does not prevent the *output* of the line from being displayed, if there is any.

So for example:

```
echo foo
```

would display this:

```
echo foo
foo
```

But add the `@` like this:

```
@echo foo
```

and all you get is the output:

```
foo
```

Once you've turned `echo off`, the `@` is useless because none of the lines are being displayed anyway.

---

### Question 2

Q2. When do I have to double-quote the value after @?

The double-quotes in your sample code have nothing to do with the `@`.  All the `@` does is cause the line to not be displayed.

Double-quotes are useful to point to a file that contains spaces in its path.  For example, if you try to run a programme like this:

```
C:\Program Files\foo.exe
```

the shell will only parse that up to the first space, so it looks for a file or command named `C:\Program`, and would return an error.

Change it to this:

```
"C:\Program Files\foo.exe"
```

and it will correctly look for `C:\Program Files\foo.exe` and run it if it exists.

In your case if you just say `gem environment`, it can find the programme named `gem.exe` and pass in `environment` as a parameter.  But if you quote it, `"gem environment"`, it is looking for something named `gem environment.exe`.

Comment: Now I see the differences. Thank you very much.