# What's the difference between @ an non @ command in batch script?

Tags: variables, batch-file, command

What's the difference between @ an non @ command in batch script?
Eg, what's the difference between
@IF
and
IF

One more question:
What's the difference between % and %% in batch script?
Eg, what's the difference between
%G
and
%%G

Thanks.

Comment: The %% is used to escape the %. See also http://stackoverflow.com/a/9397572/1410448

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`@` at the beginning of a line will execute the line but not write it to the output.  It's like turning `echo off` just for that line.  See [What does @ mean in Windows Batch scripts?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15551768/what-does-mean-in-windows-batch-scripts/15551853#15551853)

`%%` is used in `for` loops inside a batch file to escape a variable name you want to "declare".  For example:

```
for %%a in (*.txt) do ( echo %%a )
```

If you write the same `for` loop but not in a batch file, you would not double the `%`:

```
for %a in (*.txt) do ( echo %a )
```

I have never understood why, I just know that's the way it is.  :-)  Maybe someone else can elaborate.

Comment: In a batch file a single percent sign is ignored, so you need to escape them with another.

Comment: And why is a single percent ignored in a batch file but not when typed directly at the command line?  What's the logic behind the different behaviour?

Comment: Found my answer:  http://support.microsoft.com/kb/75634  Basically it's because batch files have the special condition of having to handle %1, %2, etc.