# Rename multiple files with part of line found in file using BATCH file

Tags: batch-file

I have multiple files that have a line like this somewhere in the file:

```
10.18.77.14.152392.16.APP_Ret,04/10/2018 17:21:07.592,,start,ani,1234567890
```

The line has several pieces of information and can be variable in length.

I'm trying to write a batch file that will look in a directory, search each file for the string `start,ani` and then set a variable off of the values.
Like

```
VAR1=04/10/2018
VAR2=17:21:07
VAR3=1234567890
```

Then I need to change the <kbd>/</kbd> and <kbd>:</kbd> to <kbd>_</kbd> and finally rename the file thus:

```
1234567890_04_10_201817_21_07.txt
```

I can handle changing the characters to underscores, the issue I am having is trying to extract that line and set the information into variables.

Here is what I've been playing with:

```
cd /d %tmp%
set var1=1
if %var1%==1 (
    for /F "delims=" %%a in ('findstr /I "start,ani" %tmp%\*.txt') do (
        set "var=%%a"
        echo %%a
        echo %var%
    )
)
```

My goal here was just to find the line and `set var` to the entire contents.
But when I echo var it just says `echo off`.

Comment: Long time listener, first time poster.  I should add that I'm not a programmer, I just basardize other people's hard work into a format that works for me.

Comment: A long time listner would have noted that the most common issue here is related to delayed expansion!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you wanted to go further, and split your individual lines down in order to get your required variables and rename the files, you could do so in a `call`ed label section returning to the loop for the rename.

Example, *(based on the text file snippet posted and only one matching line in any file)*:

```bat
@Echo Off
SetLocal EnableDelayedExpansion
For /F "Tokens=1* Delims=:" %%A In (
    'FindStr/RIC:",start,ani," *.txt'
) Do (
    Call :Sub "%%B"
    Echo=Ren "%%A" "!VAR3!_!VAR1!_!VAR2!%%~xA"
)
Pause
Exit /B

    :Sub
    Set "line=%*"
    Set "line=%line:,=","%"
    Set "#=0"
    For %%A In (%line%) Do (
        Set /A #+=1
        Set "VAR!#!=%%~A"
    )
    For /F "Tokens=1-6 Delims=/:. " %%A In ("%VAR2%") Do (
        Set "VAR1=%%A_%%B_%%C"
        Set "VAR2=%%D_%%E_%%F"
    )
    Set "VAR3=%VAR6%"
    For %%A In (4 5 6) Do Set "VAR%%A="
    Exit /B
```

*Remove `Echo=`, and optionally `Pause`, if the output looks good.*

Comment: Oh wow!  That is exactly what I was trying to do.  I was working with a nested if and running into exactly what Fizz suggested I might.  If I understand correctly, you are handing the renaming WHILE in the original LOOP?  Thank you both for your help, I'm on my way now...

Answer (score 0):

After I turned off the echoing of commands run, by adding `@echo off` at the top of the script, I had no issues with the script. I created a file called `file.txt`, pasted the mock line you provided, and placed this the directory stored in the `tmp` environment variable. Once i ran the script, the `var` environment variable contained the line found and it was also printed out as expected.

The script I used:

```
@echo off

cd /d %tmp%
set var1=1
if %var1%==1 (
    for /F "delims=" %%a in ('findstr /I "start,ani" %tmp%\*.txt') do (
        set "var=%%a"
        echo %%a
        echo %var%
    )
)
```

[This post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8486042/what-does-mean-in-windows-batch-scripts) has a bit more on the `@` and `echo off`.

**Update:** I'm not sure of your full scenario but this may be something you eventually run into since you're setting a variable and echoing it in a for loop. If you have two lines in a file with the token "start,ani" your output will look like the following (the file path has been removed and replaced with simply `[file path]`):

`[file path]:10.18.77.14.152392.16.APP_Ret,04/10/2018 17:21:07.592,,start,ani,1234567890`
`[file path]:11.18.77.14.152392.16.APP_Ret,04/10/2018 17:21:07.592,,start,ani,1234567890`
`[file path]:11.18.77.14.152392.16.APP_Ret,04/10/2018 17:21:07.592,,start,ani,1234567890`
`[file path]:11.18.77.14.152392.16.APP_Ret,04/10/2018 17:21:07.592,,start,ani,1234567890`

As you can see the first echo of `%var%` is the same as the last and this is because the variable is only expanded once. To get more expected output you would need to use delayed expansion:

```
@echo off
setlocal ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION

cd /d %tmp%
set var1=1
if %var1%==1 (
    for /F "delims=" %%a in ('findstr /I "start,ani" %tmp%\*.txt') do (
        set "var=%%a"
        echo %%a
        echo !var!
    )
)
```

Now the first echo of `var` will display as expected:

`[file path]:10.18.77.14.152392.16.APP_Ret,04/10/2018 17:21:07.592,,start,ani,1234567890`
`[file path]:10.18.77.14.152392.16.APP_Ret,04/10/2018 17:21:07.592,,start,ani,1234567890`
`[file path]:11.18.77.14.152392.16.APP_Ret,04/10/2018 17:21:07.592,,start,ani,1234567890`
`[file path]:11.18.77.14.152392.16.APP_Ret,04/10/2018 17:21:07.592,,start,ani,1234567890`

[This post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10558316/example-of-delayed-expansion-in-batch-file) has more info on delayed expansion.

Comment: I need to do some more research to understand the %var% versus the !var!.  But this works great!  Thank you very much.