# How do get rid of "set "JAVA_HOME_CONDA_BACKUP=" " message?

Tags: anaconda, jupyter-notebook, jupyter, conda

Every time I start my command prompt on windows and then activate my conda environment I get two messages:

```
C:\Users\texas_cactus>set "JAVA_HOME_CONDA_BACKUP="
```

and

```
C:\Users\texas_cactus>set "JAVA_HOME=C:\Users\texas_cactus\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\envs\tc35\Library"
```

Where are these messages coming from and how can I get rid of them? Google is not my friend here.

Answer (score 3):

I created an environment with `openjdk`

When I activated the `env`, I had the same echo as you (except with my path)

In `anaconda3\envs\tc35`  look for `etc\conda\activate.d`

In mine, I found `java_home.bat` with the contents

```
set "JAVA_HOME_CONDA_BACKUP=%JAVA_HOME%" 
set "JAVA_HOME=%CONDA_PREFIX%\Library"
```

Deleting `java_home.bat` stopped the echo when activating my `env`, but I'm not certain the package will work correctly after.

It's possible to comment out `set "JAVA_HOME_CONDA_BACKUP=%JAVA_HOME%"`. See [conda-forge/openjdk-feedstock](https://github.com/conda-forge/openjdk-feedstock/tree/master/recipe/scripts) to verify this doesn't lead to any adverse results.

Alternatively, as mentioned in a comment by [John Bollinger](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2402272/john-bollinger), prefix the `set` commands with an `@` (e.g. `@set "JAVA_HOME_CONDA_BACKUP=%JAVA_HOME%"`), or by prefixing the whole file with `@echo off`. The `@` suppresses echoing on a command-by-command basis, whereas `@echo off` disables echoing altogether.

- [`echo`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/administration/windows-commands/echo)
- [What does “@” mean in Windows batch scripts](https://stackoverflow.com/q/8486042/7758804)

Answer (score 2):

I also had trouble with the issue this afternoon, and it led me cannot launch my Spyder in Anaconda.

Subsequently I found the problem happened because I install the  RStudio which also install the package named "openjdk" simultaneously.

"openjdk" cause the launch conflict between Spyder and RStudio.

So, if you want to get rid of the bother from the message of "set JAVA_HOME= ", you can do the following step in your environment.

```
C:\Users\user>conda uninstall openjdk
```

Notably, if you execute the step may cause your RStudio unable to be launched.

Hope this useful.

Answer (score 0):

Depending on which version of Windows used by you such statements can also be found in `autoexec.bat` or `autoexec.nt`