# When I launch an anaconda prompt I get lots of log messages. How can I get rid of them?

Tags: keras, cmake, anaconda, conda

After installing keras and all m2w64 package my anaconda prompt now works weirdly. It always logs a plenty of messages concerning cmake and system environment variables.

I tried reverting my environment to a previous state, but that didn't work because it said target environment was missing tensorflow (but it had one).
[image]

```
C:\Users\1>set "JAVA_HOME_CONDA_BACKUP="
C:\Users\1>set "JAVA_HOME=C:\Anaconda3\Library"
C:\Users\1>SET DISTUTILS_USE_SDK=1
C:\Users\1>SET MSSdk=1
C:\Users\1>SET platform=
C:\Users\1>IF /I [AMD64] == [amd64] set "platform=true"
C:\Users\1>IF /I [] == [amd64] set "platform=true"
C:\Users\1>if defined platform (set "VSREGKEY=HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\Microsoft\VisualStudio\14.0" )  ELSE (set "VSREGKEY=HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\VisualStudio\14.0" )
C:\Users\1>for /F "skip=2 tokens=2,*" %A in ('reg query "HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\Microsoft\VisualStudio\14.0" /v InstallDir') do SET "VSINSTALLDIR=%B"
ERROR: The system was unable to find the specified registry key or value.
C:\Users\1>if "" == "" (set "VSINSTALLDIR=C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\Common7\Tools\" )
C:\Users\1>if "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\Common7\Tools\" == "" (
ECHO "Did not find VS in registry or in VS140COMNTOOLS env var - exiting"
 exit 1
)
C:\Users\1>echo "Found VS2014 at C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\Common7\Tools\"
"Found VS2014 at C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\Common7\Tools\"
C:\Users\1>SET "VS_VERSION=14.0"

C:\Users\1>echo "Found VS2014 at C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\Common7\Tools\"
"Found VS2014 at C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\Common7\Tools\"
C:\Users\1>SET "VS_VERSION=14.0"
C:\Users\1>SET "VS_MAJOR=14"
C:\Users\1>SET "VS_YEAR=2015"
C:\Users\1>set "MSYS2_ARG_CONV_EXCL=/AI;/AL;/OUT;/out"
C:\Users\1>set "MSYS2_ENV_CONV_EXCL=CL"
C:\Users\1>set "PY_VCRUNTIME_REDIST=\vcruntime140.dll"
C:\Users\1>set "CFLAGS= -MD -GL"
C:\Users\1>set "CXXFLAGS= -MD -GL"
C:\Users\1>set "LDFLAGS_SHARED= -LTCG ucrt.lib"
C:\Users\1>set "CXX=cl.exe"
C:\Users\1>set "CC=cl.exe"
C:\Users\1>IF /I [] == [win-64] (set "folder=x64" )  else (set "folder=x86" )
C:\Users\1>for /F "tokens=*" %I in ('dir "C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\*1*" /B /O:N') do for %A in (%~I) do if "%A" == "8.1" set win=%A
C:\Users\1>for %A in (10) do if "%A" == "8.1" set win=%A
C:\Users\1>if "10" == "8.1" set win=10
C:\Users\1>for %A in (8.1) do if "%A" == "8.1" set win=%A
C:\Users\1>if "8.1" == "8.1" set win=8.1
C:\Users\1>for /F "tokens=*" %I in ('dir "C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\*1*" /B /O:N') do for %A in (%~I) do if "%A" == "10" set win=%A
C:\Users\1>for %A in (10) do if "%A" == "10" set win=%A
C:\Users\1>if "10" == "10" set win=10
C:\Users\1>for %A in (8.1) do if "%A" == "10" set win=%A
C:\Users\1>if "8.1" == "10" set win=8.1
C:\Users\1>setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
C:\Users\1>if "10" == "10" (
for /F "tokens=*" %I in ('dir "C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\bin\10*" /B /O:N') do for %A in (%~I) do set last=%A
 set "sdk_bin_path=C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\bin\!last!\x86"
)  else (set "sdk_bin_path=C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\8.1\bin\x86" )
C:\Users\1>for %A in (10.0.14393.0) do set last=%A
C:\Users\1>set last=10.0.14393.0
C:\Users\1>for %A in (10.0.15063.0) do set last=%A
C:\Users\1>set last=10.0.15063.0
C:\Users\1>for %A in (10.0.16299.0) do set last=%A
C:\Users\1>set last=10.0.16299.0
C:\Users\1>for %A in (10.0.17134.0) do set last=%A
C:\Users\1>set last=10.0.17134.0
C:\Users\1>for %A in (10.0.17763.0) do set last=%A
C:\Users\1>set last=10.0.17763.0
```

Comment: @darthbith tried to do my best to edit

Comment: Have you found which bat file /script is causing this ? Refer to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52066216/how-do-get-rid-of-set-java-home-conda-backup-message

Comment: @sharkzeeh Thank you! I just fixed up the formatting a little bit :-) Hopefully that will help someone get you an answer