# command line silent installation for .exe

Tags: command-line, advanced-installer

I used advanced installer for my project and I can install my .exe using wizard, 
but I want to perform it using command line so something which can help silent installation with advanced installer ?

Comment: [`@ECHO OFF`](https://stackoverflow.com/q/8486042/2799848)

Comment: what you mean by @ECHO_OFF ?

Comment: That is how you configure a Windows command line batch script to not print executed statements.

Comment: my question is how to perform silent installation using Advanced installer with command line, so we need have to pass arguments some where to answer wizard question so that is not helpful

Comment: So if you wish to even invoke the installer from command line silently, you gotta make the statement you run execute silently too!

Comment: https://www.advancedinstaller.com/user-guide/exe-setup-file.html (see towards bottom).

Answer (score 1):

just use `/exenoui /qn` command line arguments for a silent install